# Strip all values from C# objects using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following method which is used to retrieve all values as strings from an object using reflection. The object can have IEnumerables within them and I also want to retrieve these values. A list of ignore fields also needs to be taken into account so that those field's values are not returned.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> StringContent(this object obj, IEnumerable<string> ignoreProperties = null)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties())
    {
        if (ignoreProperties != null && ignoreProperties.Contains(field.Name))
        {
            continue;
        }
        var value = prop.GetValue(obj);
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value is IEnumerable<object>)
            {
                foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<object>)value)
                {
                    foreach (var subValue in item.StringContent())
                    {
                        yield return subValue.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                yield return value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method does work perfectly and gives me the correct result. However, I need to speed it up as much as possible because this is performed a lot of times.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

** **EDIT** **

Example Test Case:

```
[TestMethod]
public void StringContent()
{
    Project project = projectA;
    List<string> ignoreFields = new List<string>() { "SalesEngineer", "CreationDate" };
    var result = project.StringContent(ignoreFields);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Count() == 26);
}
```

Project Object:

```
public class Project : IEntity
{
    public Project()
    {
        Products = new List<ProjectProducts>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string SalesEngineer { get; set; }
    public string SalesEngineerEmail { get; set; }
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Originator { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string MainClient { get; set; }
    public string Contractor { get; set; }
    public string ContractorContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContractorLocation { get; set; }
    public string Wholesaler { get; set; }
    public string WholesalerContactName { get; set; }
    public string WholesalerLocation { get; set; }
    public float EstimatedValue { get; set; }
    public float CalculatedValue { 
        get { return EstimatedValue/Convert.ToSingle(Currency != null ? Currency.Rate : (decimal)1.0); }
    }
    public int Probability { get; set; }
    public int SectorId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string LostTo { get; set; }
    public int ReasonId { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryEngineer { get; set; }
    public float SplitPercentage { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpectedOrder { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RequiredOnSiteBy { get; set; }
    public bool LightingDesignRequired { get; set; }
    public string ReasonForLightingDesign { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DesignRequiredBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FollowUp { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public bool Void { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentFolder { get; set; }

    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public virtual Reason Reason { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual Sector Sector { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectProducts> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

    public object Key
    {
        get { return Id; }
    }

}
```

Comment: The *first* thing I'd do is rename "field" to "property" everywhere in the code, given that you're not looking for fields at all. Obviously that won't speed anything up, but it'll improve the code clarity. Now, what's the current performance, and what do you need it to be? Can you provide your benchmarking example? (If you aren't benchmarking yet, that's the next thing to do...)

Comment: When profiling, the CPU percentage is 23% currently. I need to get that down as low as possible. My calling method, takes 13ms to execute. Profiling shows that this method is about the only thing using a significant amount of CPU time (the rest are 0.02%)

Comment: "as low as possible" isn't a concrete requirement. You need to have a point at which you'll stop. You should also extract this piece of work from everything else, creating a test case that *just* does this work (and obviously consumes all the results). Then you can include that test code in the question, so we can check where the time is going ourselves. At the moment we have no idea what kind of objects you're working with, how many properties you're excluding, what the type of `ignoreFields` is, etc.

Comment: Additionally, you could potentially improve performance a lot using delegates *if* you'll be doing this repeatedly for the same type a lot. But if you're not, that will just cost time instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet could you please expand and give an example

Comment: Well I'll add it as an answer *if* it's applicable, but you need to give more information so I know whether it's even applicable. I'd also want to give code with results - which I can only do with a realistic example, which is why I've asked for a benchmarking setup.

Comment: Btw, do you realize this won't do what you probably expect for (say) `List<int>`? A `List<int>` isn't an `IEnumerable<object>`, but it *is* an `IEnumerable`...

Comment: You should use Reflection.Emit or System.Linq.Expressions.Lambda to generate dynamic delegates that will work with little to no performance overhead. I will expand this to full answer in some time.

Comment: You might also want to look at https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member

Comment: I will work on an isolated test case to provide. I say as low as possible as I am unsure as to what a realistic expectation of the performance cost should be and therefore I was asking for general improvements rather than i need it to be using 5% CPU etc. The objects are fairly complex objects which i could provide an example of. There are only 2 properties being excluded currently. and as you can see from the method signature the type of ignoreFields is IEnumerable<string>()

Comment: Yes, I can tell the *declaration* type, but if there were 100 properties being ignored, there'd be a big difference between passing in a `HashSet<string>` vs a `LinkedList<string>`. The execution-time type is important.

Comment: I realise it wouldnt work in instances such as `List<int>` which is fine in our scenario as this would not be passed in. I will work on a test case and provide an object example now

Comment: I see what you mean now, but yes currently it is only 2 ignoreFields being passed in

Comment: @JonSkeet I have edited to include a test and the Project object, if you would like the other objects then please let me know

Comment: P.S. the test takes 4ms to perform. I would like that down to 1ms if possible

Comment: Well it's still incomplete, in that we don't have sample objects. Note that running a unit test like that is a bad way of measuring performance - it would be much better to use BenchmarkDotNet or similar.

Comment: Ive never heard of that ill take a look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [stringify](https://github.com/danshapir/DOTNET.Stringifier) package.

It exists in Nuget.

You can Hide parameters with `Hidden` attribute.

You can print every object with `a.stringify();`

Comment: can you give an example please

Comment: After you install this nuget, you can print every object with `.stringify()` function.